# Is reputation cap accounted for in the reputation change on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, daily-reputation-limit, score

I see that reputation scoring changed on Meta Stack Overflow to make votes worth 5 points.

This is a little complicated to phrase, but my question is:

If a user hit the daily reputation cap because of question upvotes when a question upvote was worth 10 points, but now the daily reputation cap was not reached on that, were points awarded for the votes that were received after the reputation cap was reached under the previous scoring system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit [/reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) and see the answer for yourself.

After any scoring rule changes, a full recalc is run. As the name suggests, that means your score is reset back to 1, then all votes are applied, and that becomes your new score.